# Data retrieving is taking more than 4hrs to fetch 400K records

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, ssms, azure-sql-database

I have a table with 15 million rows, it's a parent table with 12 child tables.

Even for a simple count query, it is taking hour's to complete.

```
select count(1) from table
where col_filter >= 'number'
```

`table` contains 40 columns and `col_filter` is having `varchar` data type. `col_filter` is not indexed.

Questions:

1. What should I check to find the potential issues with my table setup?
2. I am using Microsoft SQL server management studio 18, is there any tool that I can use to understand and get some recommendations to optimize the performance?
3. If indexing is the solution, is it possible to calculate how much extra space the index creation will occupy?

**Update-1**:

This table is part of other data fetch query, which contains, `cte`, `inner joins` and then using `cte` as base table which perform group by operations, the table which I posted in post is the base table inside cte, as it's taking long time even for count, I thought it would be good start to debug. Here is the full query with **estimated** [execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryjfZODo3) and **actual** [execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1NBcOPs2) which runs for 18+hours.

Note: Actual execution plan was taken from the running query as shown in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59157947/8353711)

wait_info for `select count(1) from table where col_filter >= 'number'`:

```
(35ms)PAGEIOLATCH_SH:dev-db:1(*)
(26ms)PAGEIOLATCH_SH:dev-db:1(*)
(86ms)PAGEIOLATCH_SH:dev-db:1(*)
(9ms)PAGEIOLATCH_SH:dev-db:1(*)
```

and it's actual [execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJOu6TIoh)

Any suggestions would be really appreciable.

Comment: Please do not cross post . [Data retrieving is taking more than 4hrs to fetch 400K records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76808795/data-retrieving-is-taking-more-than-4hrs-to-fetch-400k-records)

Comment: @ErgestBasha Any specific reason? I thought it's more relevant to this site, but trying my luck for solution on both sites.

Comment: *While our subject matters certainly overlap, this activity splinters answers and can cause unnecessary work for other users. Usually one of the copies of the question will either be deleted, or migrated / closed / merged* - [What topics can I ask about here?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) .  Please for performance queries see [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: Check whether the table is a heap table. I.e. a table with no clustered index.

Comment: @TiborKaraszi The table contains `nonclustered` index on a different column, which I am not using for my filter. Do you mean heap table is slow or fast?

Comment: A heap table can have lots of unused space, based on the modification pattern on that table. That might explain your case.

Comment: @TiborKaraszi Note, in his dupe question on StackOverflow, he confirms there's a clustered index too, so no heap here.

Comment: Note that your execution plan seems to indicate that the table has 15 million rows, not 1.5 million.  Unless you've set statistics on the table to make SQL Server believe that the table is 10x larger than it actually is.

Comment: @JustinCave Yes, you are correct. It contain 15 million rows, it my mistake, I will update the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've already been advised on (between both your Posts), an index on `(col_filter)` would help the example query you've provided. If you're only running aggregative queries like this, then a nonclustered columnstore index might be best so that you can get columnar compression (which will minimize disk space overhead of the index) and improve performance with batch mode operations.

Outside of that, as Martin pointed out on your other Post, 4 hours is still unusual to scan even the whole table of 1.5 million rows. But since you're on the cloud, there's a number of things that can be bottlenecking your queries. It's hard to say without seeing the [actual execution plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/analyze-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver16). You can also run [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com) in a separate query window, while you're waiting on your query to finish executing, to see what it's waiting on (wait types) and if there's any blocking processes. This would be helpful to know too.

Start with indexing, and see if that makes a significant improvement (i.e. your example query shouldn't take more than a minute - and that's slow to be honest). If it's still problematic, please update your Post with your table's definition and the actual execution plan of the slow query, which you can upload on [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan) and then link in your Post.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This table is part of other data fetch query, which contains, `cte`, `inner joins` and then using `cte` as base table which perform group by operations, the `table` which I posted in post is the base table inside `cte`, as it's taking long time even for count, I thought it would be good start to debug. Here is the full query with [execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByTinsIih).

Comment: This query runs for more than 16hrs, so I started debugging from base `table1`, where `table1` contains 1.5M, `table2` contains 130M, `table3` contains 300M rows. Thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: @Pythoncoder well on quick glance, I can see why your main query could be problematic for the tables at the sizes they are. The query isn't written in the most performant way and likely needs to be tuned. But I'd be even more curious in seeing the actual execution plan and wait types for your simple example query `select count(1) from table
where col_filter >= 'number'` which shouldn't be taking hours either. If there's a root problem that can be solved for that, it'll likely positively affect your main query too. Btw you can put updated information in your original Post so others see it too.

Comment: Thanks again for your quick response, here is the [execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkrUuaIon) for `select count(1) from table where col_filter >= 'number' `, how to check the wait types? Sure I will update the post as well.

Comment: Can you share the possible reason and suggestions for that, so that I can try out them?

Comment: @Pythoncoder "*how to check the wait types?*" - You can use [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com) to see a list of the running queries on your server and their wait types (`wait_info` column). If you run that a few times while the basic example query is running, write down the names of the wait types and please add them to your Post. Also, the execution plan you provided is the **estimated** execution plan, but if you can obtain the **actual** execution plan for your basic example query, that would be a lot more helpful.

Comment: Surprisingly, the `select count(1)...` is getting executed in 2-3 seconds, not able to get `wait_info` because of low execution time, here is the actual [execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJOu6TIoh). As no one uses dev database in night time, it may be getting executed fast because of less load? but my actual `cte` query is still running from more than 7 hours.

Comment: Added `wait_info`, it took 36 seconds after clearing cache as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1873064/8353711)

Comment: @Pythoncoder Yea a couple seconds (or under a minute with a cold cache) makes more sense. That's normal. I don't think you have any root issues affecting multiple queries then. It seems like your issue is just your main query and how it's coded. I'll try to advise with details on how to tune it when I get a chance. (Also be careful not to clear the cache in a production server unless you really intended to.)

Comment: Thanks J.D. Looking for your answer.

Comment: The query is running for more than 18hrs, and it's still running, I was able to get the execution plan from running query, can you please check that too, if it helps? updated the post with details.

Comment: As this post looks diverted to a different question, I have posted a new question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/329888/260675) with details.

Answer (score -1):

You may try this :

```sql
select count(1) from table
where col_filter >= 'number'
    FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

In Oracle we do not use `Count` - rather

```
SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE <predicate>
AND rownum =1
```

to check whether the query returns any row or not.