# How to optimize the SQL query which uses cte, group by and run for 23 hours?

Tags: sql-server, performance, ssms, azure-sql-database

I have a query which first performs joins inside `cte` and then based on cte join with other table and perform group by with some aggregations and get the top 15 records.

This query is taking 23 hours to run on Azure SQL Database.

**Details:**

Azure database pricing tier: *S6 with 750GB storage* with 20% unused storage space left

```
TableName   rows         TotalSpaceGB   UsedSpaceGB UnusedSpaceGB
table2      332,318,173  117.72         117.71      0.01
table3      153,700,352  60.78          60.76       0.01
table1      15,339,815   13.21          13.20       0.01
abctable    1,232,868    0.81           0.80        0.00
```

Actual [Execution plan with query](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1NBcOPs2)

Actual [Execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkT_84Oi2) without query using `sp_WhoIsActive`

wait type: `(14ms)PAGEIOLATCH_SH:dev-db:1(*)` or `NULL` sometimes. Got this using `sp_WhoIsActive`.

**Note:**

**Actual execution plan** was taken from the **running query** as shown in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59157947/11844406)

This tables contains clustered index on primary keys and nonclustered index on other fields which I am not using in filters or joins or order by.

`table1` is parent of `table2` and `table2` is parent of `table3`

Any advice or suggestions are highly appreciable.

Comment: Can you get the execution plan from `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_query_statistics_xml(session_id_of_long_running_session)`? This will show the progress it has made in the 20 hours it has been running

Comment: @MartinSmith It just got completed, took 23hrs. I know the session id, is there a way to get this details for the finished query?

Comment: Not with the same level of detail. Query store will have some details about resource usage and aggregated waits but it won't have the same "per operator" stats. But definitely worth looking in QueryStore for the details of that query too

Comment: @MartinSmith How to get details from QueryStore? Sorry for newbie questions.

Comment: If you expand the query store node in SSMS and choose "Top Resource Consuming Queries" and set time interval to last 24 hours I imagine this query should be pretty obvious as top consumer. You can use that to get the `plan_id` and then armed with the `plan_id` use that to query `sys.query_store_wait_stats` and `sys.query_store_runtime_stats` to get details the UI doesn't show

Comment: @MartinSmith Not sure, I can't see this query in "Top Resource Consuming Queries" for last 24 hours or 2 days :|

Comment: It looks like you still attached the **estimated** execution plan, not the **actual** plan. (There's two different similar buttons near each other in SSMS for each.) The **actual** you have to enable before running the query & will only display when the query is finished. If you run the query again & wait a minute, you can then run `sp_WhoIsActive` again with the parameter `@get_plans=1` & it'll get the live query plan for you in the `query_plan` column. If you click on it, it should show it graphically and you can see where it's stuck / taking so long. You can add that plan to your Post too.

Comment: @J.D. The query is running from databricks notebook, I got the actual execution plan from SSMS when the query is still running by using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59157947/11844406) SO answer. It took 23 hours to complete. For actual query plan do I need to run it again from SSMS and get the actual query plan or is there any other easy way?

Comment: @Pythoncoder I don't believe that SO answer gets you the actual execution plan. The easiest way is to [use SSMS and click the button to enable actual execution plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver16) before you run the query. Unfortunately you have to run the query to completion to get it. Other than that, your only other option is to see if it was captured in Query Store (like Martin suggested). Aside from that, getting the live plan with `sp_WhoIsActive @get_plans = 1` would be quicker and helpful.

Comment: @J.D. By seeing the query and the amount data, how much execution time, will you consider as a good runtime?

Comment: Or In the ideal scenario, how will good performance query look like for my usecase and what kind of indexes are considered for that?

Comment: @Pythoncoder Well, how many rows is it supposed to return? (Without the actual execution plan, I can't tell.)

Comment: @J.D. It will return around 400K records, I will update the actual execution plan, playing around with indexes as per other's suggestions, I will add more details on my explorations, but curious to know what could be considered as good runtime for this usecase!

Comment: @Pythoncoder Hard to say with that many rows. 400k is a good amount to be returning at one time. It may very well evoke index scans even with properly defined indexes, which will cause the entire tables to be scanned. If that's the case, then you may need more than just query tuning, but also some re-architecting. The `WITH (FORCESEEK)` query hint may be helpful to you in such cases too, where seeking on the indexes are truly faster. But hints should really only be used as a last resort and should be well tested before release in production code as there's risks with them. I still haven't...

Comment: ...had a chance to sit down and actually review your query in detail yet. Hopefully tonight I can take a look and give more guided advice. To answer your original question, 400k rows shouldn't take hours to retrieve though, once properly architected.

Comment: @J.D. I have updated the post by adding actual execution plan using `sp_WhoIsActive`, but it won't show me the query in the execution plan, but the query is same. Looking forward your advice :)

Comment: @Pythoncoder cool, thanks, that's definitely helpful. It exposes where the query is currently hanging. I see some cardinality estimate issues, and some actual cardinality issues by not being filtered proactively enough. There's probably some query tuning that can be done to help fix most of this. Btw, does this have to be a single query or can it be broken up into batches with temp tables? Also, just an FYI on the names of things, but this is technically not the actual execution plan either, it's the live query plan, but it's definitely more helpful than the estimated plan.

Comment: @J.D. I was running this query as `pd.read_sql(my_query)`, if batches with temp tables can be added into the `my_query` and if that works, then I can use it and I think it's possible as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57896584/8353711)

Comment: @Pythoncoder I'm not really familiar with Python but I agree that SO seems to indicate it's possible, and those people are trustworthy sources of information. Ok, good to know. If I rewrite it using temp tables, I'll let you know, and you can test it. If you run into any issues, I'll try to help overcome them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"This tables contains clustered index on primary keys and nonclustered index on other fields which I am not using in filters or joins or order by." -> you can't expect your query to run fast if your indexes aren't fit for the query and tables are this big (your query scans the whole table).

If I were you, I would take this into consideration:

- move the `WHERE pl.issuingdate > '2021-8-1'` into the CTE (your CTE could get smaller to work with if you use this condition every time and there's data significant amount of data earlier than 2021-8-1)
- make sure an index exists for every foreign key (column you join the tables on);
- index column order matters with multi-column indexes and non-equality searches; for the query you have posted, I would put on first and second place to the index the foreign key and the columns what you have in WHERE clause (for equality searches, column order is not that important, for inequality searches, it matters more)

  - for example, for table `table1`, I would create an index with columns in the following order: `CREATE INDEX ix_01 ON dbo.table1(pluigid, pmode, pltype ,plstatus)` - it contains your foreign key and the WHERE clause columns
- when experimenting with indexes, bear "5-to-5 rule" in mind, that means do not exceed roughly 5 indexes  on one table and refrain from having more than 5 columns in 1 index (given the environment we talk about is OLTP)

Please try to create indexes fit for your query, try re-running the query and let us know if this at least moves you in the right direction.

Also, besides execution plan, I would recommend running the query with `SET STATISTICS TIME, IO ON` and pasting the result from "messages" tab in SSMS to [IO statistics parser](https://statisticsparser.com/) to see what is the query doing IO wise. Learning about IO pattern would make the tuning efforts bit more effective.

Comment: Sure, I will try to create indexes as recommended and make changes in query. As this query is running for more than 23hrs now, is it possible to get statistics from running query?

Comment: You can try "live execution plan in SSMS", but this is how the query is executing execution plan-wise. I would first try to precise the indexes, then try to re-run the query with STATISTICS IO ... I expect the run-time to be way less ; In my original post, I don't explicitly mention the column issuingdate. In case the considerable amount of records is older than your search parameter, I would make sure I have an index on this column as well. Preferably as first col. of the index in case this WHERE significantly narrows down the amount of data returned